# Matrix multiplication in numpy vs normal for loop in python

Tags: python, numpy, vector, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

I thought of checking the time difference for a matrix multiplication using numpy matrix multiplication vs normal for loop method. I understand numpy will be faster because of vectorization, but I couldn't prove it using a simple code like below.

I am getting python normal for loop is faster than numpy in all of my test. What did I do wrong here?

My code:

```
# testing numpy vs normal method
def compare_np_vs_normal(datapoints):
    x = []
    for i in range(datapoints):
        x.append(math.ceil(random.random() * 10)) # random data
    
    # linear activation function
    m = math.ceil(random.random() * 10) # Random value for slope
    c = math.ceil(random.random() * 10) # Random value for intercept

    # linear activation result for all datapoints using normal method and np methods
    def normal_method():
        y = []
        for x_ in x:
            y_ = x_ * m + c
            y.append(y_)

        return y

    def np_method():
        x_ = np.c_[np.array(x),np.ones(len(x))]
        a_ = np.array([[m],[c]])
        return np.matmul(x_,a_)
        
    print("Comparing for {} datapoints".format(datapoints))
    
    print("Normal method:")
    t1 = time.perf_counter()
    y_result_normal = normal_method()
    t2 = time.perf_counter()
    print("Time taken {}".format(t2-t1))

    print("Numpy method:")
    t1 = time.perf_counter()
    y_result_np = np_method()
    t2 = time.perf_counter()
    print("Time taken {}".format(t2-t1))

    return y_result_normal, y_result_np
```

The result I get was

```
Comparing for 1000 datapoints
Normal method:
Time taken 7.759999971312936e-05
Numpy method:
Time taken 0.0007053999997879146
```

Comment: In your np_method, you set up the matrices and count that towards the runtime as well. If you take that out of the time measurement (matrices should be set up beforehand), you will see that the runtime is much faster with the vectorized version. This will get more pronounced when the size increases.

Comment: Thank you @Baradrist! I didn't realize that onetime setup of matrices would cost so much of time difference in my testing. Thanks again for your comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making an overly complicated calculation in the np_method function.
replace it with:

```
    def np_method():
        x_ = np.array(x)
        return x_ * m + c
```

to see the improvement

Comment: While it might be less complicated, the np.matmul functionality seems to be much faster (by a factor around 50!) in my tests, whereas your function is in the same order of magnitude as the for-loop. For this, I tested both versions for inputs of size 10^3 to 10^8. Can you test and confirm or reject on your end that your simplified version (while much more elegant) is really improving the calculation time?